# Summation of an infinite series from two ways leading up to two answers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series, summation-method

Compute the sum (S):

$\frac11.\frac12 + \frac12.\frac13 + \frac13.\frac14 + \frac14.\frac15 ... infinite terms + $

$\frac11.\frac12 + \frac12.\frac13 + \frac13.\frac14 + \frac14.\frac15 ... infinite terms + $

.......... $ + \frac12.\frac13 + \frac13.\frac14 + \frac14.\frac15 ... infinite terms + $

......................... $ + \frac13.\frac14 + \frac14.\frac15 ... infinite terms + $

........................................ $ + \frac14.\frac15 ... infinite terms + $

I have tried summing it column-wise and row-wise both and I get different answers both ways.

Row-wise:

each row is $\sum_{r=r}^{r=\inf}\frac{1}{(r)(r+1)}$ where $r$ is $1,1,2,3,4,5...$ for row1,row2,row3,row4,row5...

$\sum_{r}^{\inf}\frac{1}{(r)(r+1)} = \sum_{r}^{\inf}(\frac1r - \frac{1}{(r+1)}) = \frac1r$

$S_r = \frac11  + \frac11 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + ...$

Column-wise:

columns can be added to reduce the sum (S) to $S = 2.\frac11.\frac12 + 3.\frac12.\frac13 + 4.\frac13.\frac14 + 5.\frac14.\frac15 ... infinite terms $

$S_c =  \frac11 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + ...$

$S_r$ and $S_c$ differ by 1 which is clearly an error on my part somewhere. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong? My guess is that since both $S_c$ and $S_r$ diverge to $\inf$, maybe I'm doing a senseless thing trying to equate two infinities

Comment: As you suspect, $1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...$ goes to infinity. Can you see why?

Comment: @jlammy I have had to know this earlier so I know why.. not that back then I could see why haha ... The series is strictly greater than 1 + 1/2 + (1/4+1/4) + (1/8+1/8+1/8+1/8)... sum of infinite 1/2s. That would sum to $inf$

Comment: Yep, that's the classic argument, and a very cute one too :)

Comment: This is actually a proof of the fact that S diverges.

Comment: When the conclusion of a theorem says you can rearrange the order of adding infinitely many terms and still get the same sum, there's almost always a hypothesis that sums converge absolutely. In your situation, "absolutely" isn't an issue, since everything is positive. But you still need convergence, and you don't have that.

Comment: Yup. 

You are all awesome. Thanks for the help guys!! Learned a lot!